# how to pass keyboard input along to linux command?

Tags: bash

I run a linux command that sometimes asks for user input (press 1 or 2).

I always want to answer 1, how can I pass this value automatically ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the pipe `|` operator to connect the output of one command to the input of another.

```
echo 1 | command
```

If you want to repeat some input to a command, you can use `yes`. By default it sends the string "y" repeatedly but it also repeat a different string of your choice.

```
yes | cp * /tmp  # Answer "y" to all of cp's "Are you sure?" prompts.
yes 1 | command  # Answer "1" repeatedly until the command exits.
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a thought:

```
echo "1" | linux_command --with-arguments <&0
```

This works for commands which want input from stdin, because 0 is the descriptor for standard input. This question might better belong on Server Fault however...

Answer (score 2):

```
yes 1 | command
```