# Running Django migrations when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I have my Django app set up on Elastic Beanstalk and recently made a change to the DB that I would like to have applied to the live DB now. I understand that I need to set this up as a container command, and after checking the DB I can see that the migration was run, but I can't figure out how to have more controls over the migration. For example, I only want a migration to run when necessary but from my understanding, the container will run the migration on every deploy assuming the command is still listed in the config file. Also, on occassion, I will be given options during a migration such as:

```
Any objects realted to these content types by a foreign key will also be deleted.
Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'
```

How do I set up the container command to respond to this with a `yes` during the deployment phase?

This is my current config file

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: 'source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/actiate && python app/manage.py makemigrations'
    command: 'source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python app/manage.py migrate'
```

Is there a way to set these 2 commands to only run when necessary and to respond to the yes/no options I receive during a migration?

Comment: I don't think this is the right way! You should `makemigrations` in your local and then push the migrations to production. Apply migrations during deployment. You can do all decision taking stuff on your local. If by mistake you write wrong models you may end up losing data.

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure there is a specific way to answer yes or no. but you can append `--noinput` to your container command. Use the `--noinput` option to suppress all user prompting, such as “Are you sure?” confirmation messages.

```
try
    command: 'source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python app/manage.py migrate --noinput'
```

OR..
You can ssh into your elasticbean instance and run your command manually. 
Then you'll have more control over the migrations.

1. Install awsebcli with `pip install awsebcli`
2. Type `eb ssh Your EnvironmentName`
3. Navigate to your eb instance app directory with:

---

- sudo -s
- source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
- source /opt/python/current/env
- cd /opt/python/current/app
- then run your command.

  ./manage.py migrate

I hope this helps

Comment: source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate

Comment: This fix works on beanstalk the runs on amazon linux. for amazon linux 2, please refer to documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the same settings are used when migrating and running!
Thus I would recommend you change this kind of code in ***django.config***

```yaml
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

to:

```yaml
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin migrate"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: fund.productionSettings
```

as recommended [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html). This will help you avoid issues with **wrong settings** used.

[More](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/) on ***manage.py*** v.s. ***django-admin.py.***

Comment: Thank you, but please indent that last line (`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: fund.productionSettings`).

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the automatic migration that you can add to deploy script (which runs every time you update the environment, and may not be desirable if you have long running migration or other Django management commands), you can ssh into an EB instance to run migration manually.

Here is how to **manually run migration** (and any other **Django management commands**) while working with **Amazon Linux 2** (Python 3.7, 3.8) created by **Elastic Beanstalk**:

First, from your EB cli: `eb ssh` to connect an instance.

The virtual environment can be activated by
`source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate`

The manage.py can be ran by
`python3 /var/app/current/manage.py`

Now the only tricky bit is to get Elastic Beanstalk's environment variables. You can access them by `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config`, I'm not super familiar with bash script, but here is a little script that I use to get and set environment variables, maybe someone can improve it to make it less hard-coded:

```
#! /bin/bash
export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k DJANGO_SECRET_KEY)
...
```

More info regarding Amazon Linux 2 splatform script tools: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms-scripts.html

Answer (score 1):

`django-admin` method not working as it was not configured properly. You can also use `python manage.py migrate` in 
**.ebextentions/django.config**

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

Answer (score 1):

In reference to Oscar Chen answer, you can set environmental variables using eb cli with

```
eb setenv key1=value1 key2=valu2 ...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that the full output of `container_commands` is in `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log` (Amazon Linux 2 Elastic Beanstalk released November 2020).

To view this you would run:

```
eb ssh [environment-name]
sudo tail -n 50 -f /var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log
```

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere obvious and it's not displayed by `eb logs`; I found it by hunting around in /var/log.

The [Django example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) management command `django-admin.py migrate` did not work for me. Instead I had to use something like:

```
01_migrate:
  command: "$PYTHONPATH/python manage.py migrate"
  leader_only: true
02_collectstatic:
  command: "$PYTHONPATH/python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --verbosity=0 --clear"
```

To see the values of your environment variables at deploy time, you can create a debug command like:

```
03_debug:
  command: "env"
```

You can see most of these environment variable with `eb ssh; sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env`, but there seem to be some subtle differences at deploy time, hence using `env` above to be sure.

Here you'll see that `$PYTHONPATH` is being in a non-typical way, pointing to the virtualenv's `bin` directory, not the `site-packages` directory.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869414/can-stale-content-types-be-automatically-deleted-in-django) looks like it will work for you if you just want to send "yes" to a few prompts.

You might also consider the `--noinput` flag so that your config looks like:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: 'source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/actiate && python app/manage.py makemigrations'
    command: 'source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python app/manage.py migrate --noinput
```

This takes the default setting, which is "no".

It also appears that there's [an open issue/fix](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24865#no1) to solve this problem a better way.