# Commands in .ebextensions fails on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my Node.js application to AWS ElasticBeanstalk with AWS CodePipeline. Since my application is using WebSockets, I included the following config file in `.ebextensions`.

```
container_commands:
  enable_websocket:
    command: 
      sed -i '/\s*proxy_set_header\s*Connection/c \
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;\
              proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";\
          ' /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
```

However, the CodePipeline fails on the deployment process and the ElasticBeanstalk log file `cfn-init.log` says follows:

```
2020-06-18 12:43:42,345 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2020-06-18 12:43:42,352 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2020-06-18 12:43:42,355 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2020-06-18 12:43:42,359 [INFO] Running config postbuild_0_drcha
2020-06-18 12:43:42,381 [ERROR] Command enable_websockets (sed -i '/\s*proxy_set_header\s*Connection/c \
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;\
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";\
        ' /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf) failed
2020-06-18 12:43:42,381 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_drcha: Command enable_websockets failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command enable_websockets failed
2020-06-18 12:43:42,383 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2020-06-18 12:43:42,383 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command enable_websockets failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 171, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 129, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 530, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command enable_websockets failed
```

What is the reason for the failure?

Answer (score 9):

The secret here is that the full logs and tracebacks from `container_commands` are in `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log` (on Amazon Linux 2 Elastic Beanstalk released November 2020). To read this you would run:

```
eb ssh [environment-name]
sudo tail -n 50 -f /var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log
```

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere obvious and it's not displayed when you run `eb logs`. I only found it by hunting around in `/var/log`.

For readers looking to run Django management commands, see [Running Django migrations when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68493468/4522888)

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact same issue and came across the same configuration that also didn't work. After further sleuthing, I found the correct configuration (at least as of now).

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/websockets.conf":
    content: |

      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

I posted [a blog article](https://solitaired.com/websockets-elastic-beanstalk) that might be helpful if you need help on additional configuration.

Comment: This saved me. I ran into this problem after moving from `Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux` to `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.2.4 running Node.js 12`. I was using the old way to setup nginx with websockets. Thank you for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure why the error happens, but if you are using the Amazon Linux 2 platform (launched for Node.js on April 30th, 2020) then you can customize the nginx config more easily.

As described in [Extending Elastic Beanstalk Linux platforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html), you can put a custom nginx file at `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf` and the deployment will automatically use it. You may want to inspect the default config and base it on that.