# Create a bash script that doesn't prompt user for trivial responses like 'yes/Y or no/N'

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, rubygems

I am working on a bash server setup script for ubuntu 14.03 LTS. For some of the commands the script is executing, it prompts the user to input 'yes/no' or 'Y/N'. For some of these commands I have been able to pass a flag to the command in question that will auto respond with a yes. For example: `sudo apt-get install -y gcc` doesn't prompt the user.

On the other hand, I can't seem to find a way to do this for

`sudo gem source -a http://rubygems.org/`.

It keeps prompting me with `Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]`.

So far I've tried the following:

`yes | gem source -a http://rubygems.org/` which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3385064/3263538)

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First add [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem) certificate via script in this folder: {rubyfolder}\lib\ruby\2.1.0\rubygems\ssl_certs